# How to fix "Problem with Reactions (Restart bot)"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've a problem with a reaction reply System.

I want that when a user adds a reaction, that replies to a message, except that when the bot reboots it is no longer detected by the bot.

Do you know how to fix this problem?

Here is my current code :

```js
bot.on("messageReactionAdd", function(messageReaction, user){
    if(messageReaction.message.content === "Message"){
        if(user.bot){return}
        messageReaction.message.reply("It works.")
    }
})


bot.on("message", function(message){
        if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "test")){
          message.delete()
          message.member.createDM().then(m =>  m.send("Message").then(m => m.react("✅")))
        }
}
```

Comment: discord.js seems to only handle these events when the channel is currently cached. Since DMs are only temporarily cached for bots and not persistent over restarts it won't recognize the channel anymore.

Comment: @Minn
Ok but how can i do it ?

Comment: Apparently discord.js allows you to access raw events which you could then use instead, they just have a channel_id and message_id available. https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/3159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the latest version of discord.js, you can use the *Partial Events* to accomplish this.
According to the doc (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/topics/partials):

> Partials allow you to receive events that contain uncached instances, providing structures that contain very minimal data. For example, if you were to receive a messageDelete event with an uncached message, normally Discord.js would discard the event. With partials, you're able to receive the event, with a Message object that contains just an ID.

What you need to do is

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
// add "partials" in the bot options to enable partial events
const client = new Discord.Client({"partials": ['CHANNEL', 'MESSAGE']});

[...]
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async function(messageReaction, user){
  // fetch message data if we got a partial event
  if (messageReaction.message.partial) await messageReaction.message.fetch();

  if(messageReaction.message.content === "Message"){
      if(user.bot){return}
      messageReaction.message.reply("It works.")
  }
})
```

Doing this, you must be careful on your `client.on("message", ...)` calls, to avoid accessing data or method that are not available.
there is a boolean `message.partial` that you can use to discard partial message when you don't need them.